# Declaration Scope not encompassing Class in Swift

Tags: swift, scope

This code:

```
import UIKit
import CircleMenu

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let button = CircleMenu(
        frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 50, height: 50),
        normalIcon:"icon_menu",
        selectedIcon:"icon_close",
        buttonsCount: 4,
        duration: 4,
        distance: 120)

    button.delegate = self
    button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2.0
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

gives the error "expected declaration" in front of `button.delegate = self`.

Why?

Comment: Code needs to be in a function.

Answer (score 0):

typically,

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        button.delegate = self
        button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width / 2.0
        view.addSubview(button)
    }
}
```